# How to split by newline and space

Tags: java, split

I trying to split by newline and spaces but it doesn't work

```
String[] parole = stringa.split("\\s\\[\\r\\n]+");
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Show us your input, output and expected output.

Comment: what is `stringa` here? What is expected output?

Comment: Remove the backslashes before `[` and maybe a * after s. Or so.

Comment: As usual Vogella has a pretty good tutorial for this. I recommend it if youre new to regex!
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern seems strange to me. `\\s` matches all whitespace, including newline and carriage return (and space and tab). I believe you wanted,

```
String stringa = "Like\nthis\ryou see";
String[] parole = stringa.split("\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parole));
```

Output is

```
[Like, this, you, see]
```

Answer (score 0):

It will split for any non-alphanumeric character

```
String arr[] = line.split("\\W+");
```

Though even not recommended to use try to play around with StringTokenizer class.

```
List<String>  list = new ArrayList<String>();
String message = "This\nis\tthe new beginning of something like that, is it?";
String delim = " \n\r\t";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(message,delim);
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    list.add(st.nextToken());
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, you could use [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) in the [Apache Commons libraries](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/). See the split, splitByCharacterType and other 'split' methods.

Comment: You should provide enough informations in your answer that it stays useful even if the links die. Read [answer].

Comment: Point taken. But if Apache Commons goes offline there will be bigger things to concern us.

Comment: Possibly but it could be moved to another url for example without the previous ones redirecting to the new.